# Getting the SAXParseException

Tags: java, xml

I am using the SAXParser to parse the xml content and validating against DTD file.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "dtdfilename" must match "((feild1?,feild2?,feild3?,source*,language*,feild4?,vehicle, etc.)) there are some other fields defined in the dtdfilename.dtd file.
```

below is the dtd file declaration.

```
<!ELEMENT vip ((field1?, field2?, field3?, source*, language*,etc... >
<!ELEMENT source (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>.
```

In the xml String I am getting all the tags which are mentioned in the dtd file but while parsing the xml string it is trowing the exception.Please help me out for the same.`